# Android apk Build output folder is getting spammed with lot of apks with timestamps

Tags: android, android-studio

Hie I am currently running on Android Studio 3.4.2

For the android project which I am working on

the make project (ctrl + F9) is generating new apks in the following location

> app/build/outputs/apk

After considerable and Resonable amount of time and resonable buids this folder got spammed with lot of apk files.

is there a setting or configuration to keep only last generated apk in the location.

Comment: by default it does not build APK files with timestamps. It should have been configured that way by you or other developer, likely in `build.gradle` file

Comment: what can be gradle configuration which leads to this ?

Comment: sorry, I can't list all 100 000 000 possible configurations leading to this. Instead you should show your `build.gradle`

Comment: An Example kind of... or a idea kind of

Comment: `Instead you should show your build.gradle`